# Variable name expansion multiple substitution

Tags: bash, glob

I'm wondering how to substitute multiple patterns with variable expansion.

```
VAR=A_B_C_D_E
```

Result I want is `A_C_E` without using temp variable.

```
RESULT_TMP=${VAR/_B/}
RESULT=${RESULT_TMP/_D/}
```

I did some trial like this:

```
${${VAR/_B/}/_D/}
```

without any success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this glob pattern in BASH string substitution:

```
s='A_B_C_D_E'
echo "${s//_[BD]/}"
A_C_E
```

`_[BD]` will match `_B` or `_D` and `//` will do global replacement.

---

**EDIT:** On additional question of:

> but in case where B and D are strings: `A_FOO_C_BAR_E`

You can use `extglob` in that case:

```
shopt -s extglob

s=`A_FOO_C_BAR_E`
echo "${s//_@(FOO|BAR)/}"
A_C_E
```

Comment: Fine, but in case where B and D are strings: A_FOO_C_BAR_E